# onclick button only one div id is in call action

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have created button that view the elements that is hidden onclick but there are many div with same id but it  i want to hide all but its hidding only one i am using below code but its just viewing or hidding, the first div only hidding onclick rest its not hidding

```
<button onclick="myFunction()" class="btn-custom">View the Picture</button>
<div id=hide></div>
<div id=hide></div>
<div id=hide></div>
<div id=hide></div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("hide");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: IDs **must** be unique, Try classes instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML is invalid - `id`s must be unique.

Instead, use a class to identify the elements and [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to select all of them:

```html
<div class=hide>a</div>
<div class=hide>b</div>
<div class=hide>c</div>
<div class=hide>d</div>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Toggle</button>
<script>
  function myFunction() {
    var x = document.querySelectorAll(".hide");
    x.forEach(y => {
      if (y.style.display === "none") {
        y.style.display = "block";
      } else {
        y.style.display = "none";
      }
    })
  }
</script>
```